# Implementing multiple interfaces with same method names and varying parameters in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, g++, clang

I'm trying to create a class in C++ that implements multiple interfaces that have the same method names but have varying signatures.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IA {
public:
    virtual void method(int i) = 0; // Signature is different from IB::method

    virtual ~IA() { }
};

class IB {
public:
    virtual void method(const string& s) = 0; // Signature is different from IA::method

    virtual ~IB() { }
};

class MyClass : public IA, public IB {      
    virtual void IA::method(int i) {
        cout << "IA::method " << i << endl;
    }

    virtual void IB::method(const string& s) {
        cout << "IB::method " << s << endl;
    }

    virtual ~MyClass() { }
};
```

This class compiles using Visual C++ 2017. However, I would like to separate the method implementations from the class header but moving the implementation outside of the class declaration is causing compile errors.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
class MyClass : public IA, public IB {
    virtual void IA::method(int i);
    virtual void IB::method(const string& s);

    virtual ~MyClass() { }
};

void MyClass::IA::method(int i) {
    cout << "IA::method " << i << endl;
}

void MyClass::IB::method(const string& s) {
    cout << "IB::method " << s << endl;
}
```

Visual C++ 2017 reports this error:

> "C2509 method: member function not declared in 'MyClass'"

Out of curiosity, I compiled the two class declarations using other compilers (g++ and clang) and they both failed to compile.

Is this some Visual C++ specific behavior?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to mark your functions as so: `IA::method`

The difference is done by the calling part of the signature.

```
class IA {
public:
    virtual void method(int i) = 0; // Signature is different from IB::method

    virtual ~IA() { }
};

class IB {
public:
    virtual void method(const string& s) = 0; // Signature is different from IA::method

    virtual ~IB() { }
};

class MyClass : public IA, public IB {
public:    
    void method(int i) override { // No need for IA::method
        cout << "IA::method " << i << endl;
    }

    void method(const string& s) override { // No need for IB::method
        cout << "IB::method " << s << endl;
    }

    virtual ~MyClass() { }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't compile on clang-900.0.39.2. On which compilers have you tried this code?

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler but you need to keep the using namespace std and probably include <string>